Not able to send mail using send-mgusermail
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider..ctor(Azure.Core.TokenCredential, System.String[], Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure.ObservabilityOptions, System.String[])'.
I am trying to get a mail from the powershell script. I have newly created an automation account and added proper powershell modules to it. still iam getting this error. Is this any license issue for the user or any access issue. Can any body help me out with this.
This is the script and it had proper modules still getting the error. i am expecting a mail from user.
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $tenant -Credential $credential -nowelcome

$userId = "DathaSaiKonyala@agent123321.onmicrosoft.com"


$message = @{
    subject = "Expire notification"
    body = @{
           contentType = "Text"
        content = "Hello Team,"
     }
    toRecipients = @(@{emailAddress = @{address = "mohammednizamuddin@gmail.com"}})
}


try {
    Send-MgUserMail -UserId $userId -Message $message
}
catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred:" -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "Detailed error information:"
    $_ | Format-List * -Force
}

